# Clear Absolute Cache on Application close Ipad app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am saving Images in NSCachesDirectory in a App. At the end of app execution i would like to clear all temporary cache. Is there a way to force clear all cache on application exit. I do realise the local folder keeps cache for 3 days..but my requirement is to force clear the Cache. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do the trick, just substitute the name of your cache directory...

```
    NSString *cacheDirectoryName = [self getCacheDirectoryName];
    NSArray *items = [fileManager directoryContentsAtPath:cacheDirectoryName];
    for (NSString *item in items)
    {
      NSString *path = [cacheDirectoryName stringByAppendingPathComponent:item];
      NSError *error = nil;
      [fileManager removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];
      [error release];
    }
```

Then call the code in your AppDelegate applicationWillTerminate method.